# TypeScript; extra semicolon generated in for-loop

Tags: typescript

The following code compiles in TypeScript 0.9

```
export class TestType { }
export class SomeClass 
{
    public set SomeProperty(v: TestType) { }
    public get SomeProperty(): TestType {
       for (var k = 0; k < 77; k++)
       {
        //whatever
       }
       return new TestType();
    }
}
```

It generates the following (incorrect) JavaScript which contains an additional semicolon in the for-loop;

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
var TestType = (function () {
    function TestType() {
    }
    return TestType;
})();
exports.TestType = TestType;
var SomeClass = (function () {
    function SomeClass() {
    }
    Object.defineProperty(SomeClass.prototype, "SomeProperty", {
        get: function () {
            for (this.k = 0;; k < 77; k++) {
            }
            return new TestType();
        },
        set: function (v) {
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return SomeClass;
})();
exports.SomeClass = SomeClass;
});
```

The problem occurs both in Visual Studio and in the [online playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/). The error only seems to disappear when the type specification (:TestType) is dropped.

This is expected behavior or did I miss the completely obvious somewhere?

Comment: The fix for this can be found in the new 0.9.0.1 release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1167) that will be fixed in an upcoming release of TypeScript along with a few other critical issues. Removing the type annotation is the best available work-around.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Bit surprised this bug passed through the testing nets. Expected more a silly mistake on my side.

Comment: Fixed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/06/28/announcing-typescript-0-9-0-1.aspx